# Git command from ruby

Tags: ruby, git

Why this Ruby code doesn't work? It's supposed to clone a git repository from a remote server.

```
pipe = IO.popen( 'git clone myUserId@10.10.0.53:/prj/Common/git/MyProject', "w+"  )
pipe.puts 'mySecretPassword'
pipe.close_write
```

Thanks.

Comment: could you kindly tell us how exactly it doesn't work - the output, errors etc

Comment: Sorry. You're right. The problem is... there is no error at all, but git doesn't get the password I provide with `pipe.puts`

Comment: Finally I got the problem, but not the solution. The problem is GIT reads the password from the screen and not on the standard input. How can I solve this?

Comment: Setting GIT_ASKPASS to a script that provides the password doesn't work. I'm afraid my question was incomplete: I omitted to write that the server is configured to use SSH.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why it's not working but if you want to work with Git repo in your Ruby app it's good idea to use one of Gems that provide API for Git (i.e. [git](https://rubygems.org/gems/git)).

Comment: The gem you suggested can't clone a remote repository: you cannot provide a password. I'm afraid your answer is not so useful, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a git wrapper for ruby such as this one. Makes everything simpler https://github.com/libgit2/rugged